# How to remove a swift 2 array element is not at index

Tags: arrays, swift2

How to remove a swift 2 array element is not at index?

---

```
protocol Food { //Еда
    var name: String {get}
    func taste() -> String
    var pr: Int {get}
}

protocol Storable: Food {
    var expired: Bool {get}
    var daysToExpire: Int {get}
}

class Apple: Food { //Яблоко
    var name = "Яблоко"
    func taste() -> String {
        return "Сладкое"
    }
    var pr = 0
}

class Grapes: Storable { //виноград
    var name = "Виноград"
    func taste() -> String {
        return "Кислый"
    }
    var pr = 0
    var expired = false
    var daysToExpire = 5
}

class Banana: Storable { //Банан
    var name = "Банан"
    func taste() -> String {
        return "Сладкий"
    }
    var pr = 0
    var expired = false
    var daysToExpire = 9
}


class Potato: Food { //картошка
    var name = "Картошк"
    func taste() -> String {
        return "Сладкая"
    }
    var pr = 1
}

class Bow: Food { //Лук
    var name = "Лук"
    func taste() -> String {
        return "Горький"
    }
    var pr = 1
}

class Carrot: Food { //морковь
    var name = "Морковь"
    func taste() -> String {
        return "Сладкая"
    }
    var pr = 1
}

var apple = Apple()
var grapers = Grapes()
var banana = Banana()
var potato = Potato()
var bow = Bow()
var carrot = Carrot()

var basket: [Food] = [apple, grapers, banana, potato, bow, carrot]

func bite(oneBite: [Food]) {
    for bites in basket {
        print("Кусаем \(bites.name), ооо на вкус \(bites.taste())")
    }
}

bite(basket)

var fridge = [Storable]()//пустой массив типа Storable холодильник

for prod in basket {
    if let storableProduct = prod as? Storable where storableProduct.expired == false {
        fridge.append(storableProduct)
    }
}

var trash = [Storable]() //пустой массив типа Storable мусорка

for i in fridge {
    if i.daysToExpire > 6 {
        fridge.removeAtIndex(i)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all please post the code rather than screenshots. Nobody who is willing to help is also willing to retype the code for testing.

The index variable `i` in the loop is a `Storable` object, not an `Int` index, that's exactly what the error message says.

Using `enumerate` you get the index and the object

```
for (i, storable) in fridge.enumerate {
   if storable.days ... {
     fridge.removeAtIndex(i)
  }
}
```

But be aware that you certainly will run into the next problem if you are removing items from the object you are enumerating just now.